# What jobs do droids serve in?

Tags: robots, questionable-content

[Questionable Content comic strip #3088](http://www.questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=3088) and the few following strips suggest that some droids believe that droids should not apply to the military, yet Bubbles used to serve there. This makes me ask the following more general question.

Out of the jobs that humans used to take before the spread of droids, **in which jobs are there a high number of droids working**?

Are human temporary workers in agriculture now competing with droids who can do the same job?  Are governments full of droid bureaucrats?  Are human children taught by droid teachers?

Comment: Raise your hand if you came here thinking it was a Star Wars question :)

Comment: @DVK: These are not the droids you're looking for.

Comment: OP, why don't you read the comic? That's the single authoritative source.

Comment: Droid refers to a robot within the Star Wars universe. The same term does not apply in the real world, where droid could be short for "Android", which is a machine that emulates human form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Questionable Content universe, they're called **AnthroPCs**, not droids.

AnthroPCs have sentience, complete free will, and they **do not** have to obey the three laws of robotics.

From [this QA](http://jephjacques.com/post/10973725252/qa-dump-06) from [the tumblr](http://jephjacques.com/) of Jeph Jacques, the creator of Questionable Content:

> > How fairly do employers treat AnthroPCs applying for jobs? Why did Momo have so much trouble finding work?
>
> It varies from place to place, region to region. I imagine there are anti-robot jerks, just like there are racist jerks. Momo had trouble finding work because it’s generally pretty tough to find work here in the Pioneer Valley, especially if you don’t have any prior experience. Living here is great if you can bring work with you, but finding a job here can be tricky.
>
> > A question about AnthroPC rights in your latest QA Dump got me wondering about their level of free will. Do they have some sort of rules guiding what they can and can’t do, like the three laws of robotics, or do they have complete free will and could disobey and leave their owners, and even try and take over the world or something if they wanted?
>
> Complete free will. Like I’ve said before, it’s a good thing they seem to like us.

From [this reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/comments/md8pd/i_am_jeph_jacques_author_of_questionable_content/):

> > Also, if AnthroPCs can take human form, how do any of the characters have jobs? One would think that AnthroPCs would make much better workers than humans, especially at low-skill low-wage jobs such as working at a coffee shop
>
> AnthroPCs can do some jobs better than humans, but can also get just as bored and miserable as humans.

From [another QA](http://jephjacques.com/post/11678709862/qa-dump-12):

> > So, about Anthro PC’s. You’ve implied they could take over the world in the past. You’ve also shown us that they can get jobs and function. We’re watching Momo download either the entire library, or the reference system. So, this leads to the question: Why do robots not replace people in jobs? (A key cornerstone in all fictitious environments with robots is how they handle that question.) My thought was, “They have personalities too” and “Most choose not to work.” Am I right?
>
> They replace people to some extent, but they also replace nonsentient machines in a lot of other fields. Also some are lazy.

So, AnthroPCs **could** get jobs in agriculture, **but only if they felt like it**. If it's a boring or menial job, then an AnthroPC can become just as bored of it as a human can.

That's as close to an answer as I can get you, but we haven't really seen every nook and cranny of the society in QC, so it's hard to be more definitive than that.

[This AnthroPC wiki article](http://questionablecontent.wikia.com/wiki/AnthroPC) contains more information you might be interested in.

This was also briefly discussed in [QC 3778](https://questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=3778):

[image: QC 3778]

Comment: You're right, the terms "robot" and "AnthroPC" are  used much more often in the comics, although http://www.questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=3004 and http://www.questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=3074 says "droid".

Answer (score 4):

The implication seems to be that robots (Anthro-PCs) can, and do work in pretty much every industry that humans work in. There's even a set of laws that govern their rights to employment. That being said, there's a considerable amount of prejudice

[image: half of Questionable Comic strip 2721]

Answer (score -3):

Most droid-android-robot literature is heavy influenced by the Asimov's Supreme Rules, wich state that a robot cannot harm a human being.  That make most fictious robots unable to be soldiers, with the notable exception of the Terminator series, on which, in the long term, robots are protecting the continuity of the human species by killing them, the same theory behind the I Robot movie (not the I Robot books by Asimov, which are completely different).

So, you can speculate that most robot jobs are the ones that humans don't want to do, making honor to the original meaning of the word (slave, in czech language).  That does not leave out the old conflict "aliens stealing our jobs", now represented by machines, wich in fact is a conflict as old as the steam machine.

I think you are on the right track, guessing that old, repetitive and less gratificant jobs are left to droids, with a lot of poor people fighting for the same jobs.

Comment: Do you have any citations from QC itself, or its author, to back up this speculation?